# Rudin's PMA Theorem 4.8

Tags: metric-spaces

**Here is rudin's statement**

**Theorem 4.8** A mapping $f$ of a metric space $X$ **into** a metric space $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

**Theorem 4.8 (corollary)** A mapping $f$ of a metric space $X$ **into** a metric space $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ for every closed set $C$ in $Y$.

This follows from the theorem, since a set is closed if and only if its complement is open, and since $f^{-1}(E^{c})=[f^{-1}(E)]^{c}$ for every $E \subset Y$

**Here is my question**

We know it is $X$ mapping into $Y$, then $f(X)\subset Y$, maybe Y contains some elements $\notin f(X)$

I want to know should these elements be considered in $V$ and $C$?

Comment: Sure, $Y$  may contain some elements $\notin f(X)$ but what is the problem with that?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy
For example, C is a closed set which contains some of such elements, does $f^{-1}(C)$ have some meanings when applies for these elements?

Comment: If $f: X \to Y$ and $A \subseteq Y$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ is defined as $\{x \in X : f(x) \in A\}$. This always makes sense. (It may be the empty set).

Comment: The inverse image of $C$ is a union of all preimages of each element, Inverse images of such elements will be the empty set.

Comment: @ganesh Thanks!

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks!